# Connect to mongodb with TLS

Tags: mongodb, ssl

Windows version : 10
Mongodb version : 6.0.2
Tools : mongosh

Hello, I am trying to set up mongodb with TLS and accessing the mongodb instance through mongosh using client certificate.
I followed the steps mentionned here : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-transport-encryption/ to configure the mongod with TLS.

The configuration is successful and I can successfully start mongodb using below command :

mongod --tlsMode requireTLS --tlsCertificateKeyFile C:\OpenSSL\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\test-server1.pem

my mongod.cfg has the below settings for network:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  tls:
       mode: requireTLS
       tlsCertificateKeyFile: C:\OpenSSL\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\test-server1.pem
```

My issue is when trying to connect through mongosh, I am getting below error:

```
Connecting to:          mongodb://localhost:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&tls=true&tlsCertificateKeyFile=C%3A%5COpenSSL%5Copenssl-0.9.8k_X64%5Cbin%5Ctest-client.pem&tlsCAFile=C%3A%5COpenSSL%5Copenssl-0.9.8k_X64%5Cbin%5Ctest-ca.pem&appName=mongosh+1.6.0
MongoServerSelectionError: read ECONNRESET
```

I used steps on

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/appendix/security/appendixC-openssl-client/#std-label-appendix-client-certificate  to generate client certificate above.

Server certificate was generated following these steps :

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/appendix/security/appendixB-openssl-server/#std-label-appendix-server-certificate

The message

MongoServerSelectionError: read ECONNRESET

is not giving any value in understanding the error. I understand its an openssl error but why am getting this error is unclear.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the mongo log file, it is also defined in the config file. Check the certificate with `openssl verify -CAfile C:\OpenSSL\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\test-ca.pem C:\OpenSSL\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\test-server1.pem` and check the connection with `openssl s_client -CAfile C:\OpenSSL\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\test-ca.pem -brief -connect localhost:27017 <<< "Q"`

Comment: Maybe update your openssl. Version 0.9.8 is from 2005 and a bit outdated.

Comment: When you run `mongod --tlsMode requireTLS --tlsCertificateKeyFile C:\OpenSSL\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\test-server1.pem` then the config file `mongod.cfg` is not used! Use `mongod --config <path>\mongod.cfg` if you like to use the configuration file. I recommend not mixing configuration file and command line options, use only one of them.

Comment: Maybe as a starting point, remove `tlsCertificateKeyFile=C%3A%5COpenSSL%5Copenssl-0.9.8k_X64%5Cbin%5Ctest-client.pem` from connection string and add `net.tls.allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: false` (or `--tlsAllowConnectionsWithoutCertificates`) Then you cannot get confused by server and client certificate. You may add it again, after you got it working for server certificate.

Comment: ok. I had the following error in log. 
{"error":{"code":141,"codeName":"SSLHandshakeFailed","errmsg":"SSL handshake received but server is started without SSL}
I started mongodb again with new tls config and now its ok. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the following error in log.

{"error":{"code":141,"codeName":"SSLHandshakeFailed","errmsg":"SSL handshake received but server is started without SSL}

I started mongodb again with new tls config and now its ok. Thanks –

mongod --tlsMode requireTLS --tlsCertificateKeyFile C:\OpenSSL\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\test-server1.pem

mongosh --tls --host localhost --tlsCertificateKeyFile  C:\OpenSSL\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\test-client.pem  --tlsCAFile  C:\OpenSSL\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\test-ca.pem

We can also store the tls options in the config file

```
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  tls:
       mode: requireTLS
       tlsCertificateKeyFile: C:\OpenSSL\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\test-server1.pem
```

Comment: Actually this surprises me. The mongod server should not be able to verify client certificate `test-client.pem` because you did not provide the `CAFile`. Either mongod server ignores the client certificate or it uses some system CA (which does not work on my Windows machine)